# Strange behavior of WPF Maximize Window in dot net core project. "this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized" not function as expected

Tags: wpf, .net-core

This line of code

this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;   // to maximize current window

does not seem to function correctly in dotnet 5 and later.

This can be demoed with a very simple project.

1. Create a new dotnet 5 or 6 wpf project
2. Add the following code in the window xaml properties

   ```
        Width="500"

        Height="Auto" 

        SizeToContent="Height"

        ResizeMode="CanResize"            

        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
   ```
3. Add the following xaml code inside the main grid

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="Purple">
            <Button Width="100" Height="40" Margin="20" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" 
                    Click="Button_Click_Max">Max</Button>
            <Button Width="100" Height="40" Margin="20" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30"
                    Click="Button_Click_Min">Min</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1">
            <Border Background="AliceBlue" 
                    BorderThickness="20" 
                    BorderBrush="Purple"
                    Width="600"
                    Height="800">
                <TextBlock FontSize="70" Foreground="DarkGreen" FontWeight="Bold" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        1 <LineBreak/>
                        2 <LineBreak/>
                        3 <LineBreak/>
                        4 <LineBreak/>
                        5 <LineBreak/>
                        6 <LineBreak/>
                        7 <LineBreak/>
                        8 <LineBreak/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Viewbox>
```

4. Add the following two event handlers in the code behind

```
  private void Button_Click_Max(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void Button_Click_Min(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState=WindowState.Normal;
        }
```

5. This is it. The first click event does not function as expected.

If you run this app and hit the Max button.  You will only see the majority of the screen, but not all: meaning you will not see all the numbers. I moved it around multiple monitors, the bottom is always hidden.

Interestingly. If you hit the system max button on the main window frame, the little square, it will function correctly, and after that, you try to hit the Max button again, and it will function correctly as well, meaning you can see all the numbers.

Does anyone know something about this and how to fix it.  Right now my work around is to hit the system max button first.

Thank you very much if you can shade any light on this.

Comment: Maximize and minimize must work. Hard to believe that you are the first one to discover this bug after all the time. Your observed behavior is not reproducible. Maybe you should create a clean solution to test your code.

Comment: I am scratching my head as well.  I create a clean code project and here is the link https://github.com/fengfranklu/MaxWinTest. You can download and try it. My workstation is a MacBook Pro and uses Bootcamp to run Windows 10. I connected to two external monitors, and they all show the same behavior.  The extra xaml code is just to make it easy to see the behavior.  I do need: Height="Auto" 
SizeToContent="Height" for the window property.    Again, the system max button works, they must do something differently.

Comment: I guess the environment is a valuable information. Could be driver related.  While the Maximize button is part of the window chrome and therefore part of the OS, the button command will be properly executed by the OS. But it seems that the Mac drivers return the wrong screen parameters. The `Window.WindowState` is handled by the framework. It will query the screen parameters to invoke low-level operations to maximize the window. Due to the wrong screen parameters the window size is wrong. That's my theory. WPF could track the window size after the chrome button click (to get the correct size).

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me.  Thank you so much for commenting my question  and give good suggestion.    Thanks BionicCode!!!

Comment: And when you remove the  SizeToContent setting it behaves normal? Because you mentioned these settings as if they make a difference.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I remove "SizeToContent", it behaves normal.     Height="Auto" or a fixed size does not matter.   My application use the window to host a usercontrol that has different sizes depend on the type of content, that is why the "SizeToContent"

Comment: Then you can try to handle the Loaded event and set SizeToContent to Manual. This way you size the window on startup. Usually you don't want to actively change the window size while the application is running. I guess every user would find it annoying if e.g. a browser suddenly changes its size. The recommended approach is to wrap the content like your UserControl into a ScrollViewer. If your content exceeds the height of the Window the user has scroll bars to bring the hidden content into view - or he can resize the window.

Comment: I tried the demo project on a normal windows desktop, but it still shows the same behavior. So it is not related to the BootCamp driver.  And it will function correctly if I hit the system max button once, even if I move the application window to a different monitor.  Seems like a bug related to SizeToContent and WindowState.Maximized.  Am I hitting the jackpot?

Comment: Are you using a vertical monitor? I had the problem you mentioned when launching your app when one of my monitors was vertical. When I set my monitor to landscape, it behaved normally. I guess the app gets the highest monitor scale when it first starts. Once you zoom in from the upper right corner, it takes the values of the relevant monitor and Min Max works without any problems after that.

Comment: The problem is not only in .NET 5. It looks the same as in previous versions.

Comment: Yes.  One of my monitors is vertical. This could be why as you described. I will try to set it to landscape once I get back to my desk later.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes Ozgur.   It is related to the vertical monitor.  Once I reset it to landscape.  It all works fine. Thanks for figuring this out.  I guess we ran into a rare edge case here.